# Excel formatting using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False, startrow=1, header=False)
wb = xl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

sheet.merge_cells('A1:I1')
cell = sheet.cell(row=1, column=1)
cell.value = "Ihsedu Agrochem (P) Ltd., Jagana"
cell.font = Font(size=20, b=True, name="Calibri")
cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
sheet.row_dimensions[1].height = 35

for cell_h in sheet['2:2']:
    cell_h.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
    cell_h.font = Font(size=14, b=True, name="Calibri")
    #cell_h.row_dimensions[2].height=20
    # cell_h.column_dimensions[2].width = 20
wb.save(excelfilename)
```

I want to formate row and column dimension using 2 last line, but the 2 last line generates the error.

Comment: can you post some more code included the opening of excel and what is the sheet name?

Comment: df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False, startrow=1, header=False)
wb = xl.load_workbook(excelfilename)
sheet = wb.active

for cell_h in sheet['2:2']:
    cell_h.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
    cell_h.font = Font(size=14, b=True, name="Calibri")
    #cell_h.row_dimensions[2].height=20
    # cell_h.column_dimensions[2].width = 20
wb.save(excelfilename)

Comment: updated all code for reference.